# Перебираю цикл в Python и теряю один элемент - почему?

Tags: python, циклы, sympy

Мне необходимо получить такой результат:

> (x - 30)*(x - 20)*(x - 10) + (x - 20)*(x - 10) + (x - 10)

И, вроде бы, написанный код должен к этому вести, но слагаемое `(x - 10)` теряется. В чем загвоздка?

Код:

```
from sympy import symbols
x = symbols('x')
dig_list = [10, 20, 30]

poly_0 = x-dig_list[0]
for i in range(1, len(dig_list)):   
    poly_n = poly_0 * (x-dig_list[i])
    # кажется, что при первом проходе poly_0 в summa должен давать искомое слагаемое:
    summa = poly_0 + poly_n
    poly_0 = poly_n
print(summa)
```

Comment: `[i for i in range(1, 3)]` => `[1, 2]`

Comment: На первой же итерации цикла у тебя i=1. Собственно, можно инициализировать summa перед циклом. `summa = poly_0`, а можно не делать исключение для первого элемента и переделать цикл на от 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sympy import symbols
x = symbols('x')
dig_list = [10, 20, 30]

temp = 1
summa = 0
for i in dig_list: 
    temp *= (x - i)
    summa += temp
print(summa)
```

---

Объяснение:

1. `temp = 1` – начинаем из *нейтрального элемента для умножения*, т.к. temp будем только умножать (`*=`).
2. `suma = 0` – начинаем из *нейтрального элемента для складывания*, т.к. значение suma будем только увеличивать (`+=`).
3. `for i in dig_list:`– не надо применять индекс в цикле — нам не надо индекса, а только элементы списка.
4. В самом цикле только

   - умножаем предыдущее значение `temp` (`*=`) и
   - увеличиваем предыдущее значение `suma` (`+=`).

Answer (score 2):

summa же теряет старое значение

```
poly_0 = x-dig_list[0]
summa = poly_0
for i in range(1, len(dig_list)):
    poly_n = poly_0 * (x-dig_list[i])
    # кажется, что при первом проходе poly_0 в summa должен давать искомое слагаемое:
    summa += poly_n
    poly_0 = poly_n
print(summa)

>>>  x + (x - 30)*(x - 20)*(x - 10) + (x - 20)*(x - 10) - 10
```

Comment: получил результат `x + (x - 30)*(x - 20)*(x - 10) + (x - 20)*(x - 10) - 10`. Можно ли добиться, чтобы (x-10) было скобкой?

Comment: @Alex, нет, это не возможно, SymPy имеет свой собственный алгоритм для выдачи результата. Иногда с новой версией формат изменяют. (Да, функциями как `simplify()`, `expand()`, `factor()` возможно форму результата изменить, но нет так, как вы хотите.)

Answer (score 1):

можно так попробовать наверное

```
import math

def summa(x, dig_list):
    subs = [x - v for v in dig_list]

    return sum(math.prod(subs[i:]) for i in range(len(subs)))

print(summa(1, [30, 20, 10]))
```

только заметьте, что массив начальный я в обратном порядке передаю, ну или если это не хочется, то сделать `dig_list[::-1]`

ну или если хочется в одну строку

```
summa = lambda x, dig_list: sum(__import__('math').prod([x - v for v in dig_list[i:]]) for i in range(len(dig_list)))

print(summa(1, [30, 20, 10]))
```

Comment: Почему-то вижу исключение: `AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'prod'`

Comment: в 3.10 prod точно есть

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import symbols
x = symbols('x')
dig_list = [10, 20, 30]

poly_0 = x-dig_list[0]
for i in range(len(dig_list)):   # Считает с нуля до len(dig_list) - 1
    poly_n = poly_0 * (x-dig_list[i])
    # кажется, что при первом проходе poly_0 в summa должен давать искомое слагаемое:
    summa = poly_0 + poly_n
    poly_0 = poly_n
print(summa)
```

В программировании обычно (чаще всего) отсчет ведется с нуля, запомни это правило.

Comment: Насчет отсчета с нуля - согласен. 
Получил результат: `(x - 30)*(x - 20)*(x - 10)**2 + (x - 20)*(x - 10)**2`